# Managing shared content in Craft

Tags: templating, include

I'm fairly new to Craft. I have a question about how to manage and setup the editing of shared content in Craft which is used on multiple pages.

As an example I have a Mailing List signup element which will be used across multiple pages. In my templates I'm using an include:

```
{% include "includes/_mailing-signup" %}
```

I come from Perch where you could make a Region of content shared which would take it out of the page and into a 'Shared' area in the admin.

What's the best way to approach this in Craft where content can be edited in one central location to update on all page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should look into "Globals" for content you want to edit, and re-use throughout your entire site.

http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/globals

Comment: Super, thanks. I just figured it out (see below). I love how helpful the Craft community is.

Answer (score 2):

I've figured it out.

To anyone who has a similar question. They are called Globals.

Set them up from the settings area with fields then you can reference them from your template like below.

```
{{ mailingList.textArea }}
```

*mailingList* is the handle of my Global Set and *textArea* is the field.

Info:
http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/globals